# Can't find why this js/jQuery to list last 12 months generates "undefined" warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't get rid of the "undefined" message that shows in the html inside the ul tag and before the first li.

HTML:

```
<ul id="monthFilters" class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"></ul>
```

js/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var theMonths = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
    var theMonthNames = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var today = new Date();

    var aMonth = today.getMonth();
    var aYear = today.getFullYear();

    var i;
    var monthList;

    for (i=0; i<12; i++) {

        monthList += '<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="?addedin=' + aYear + '-' + theMonths[aMonth] + '">'+theMonthNames[aMonth]+'</a></li>';

        aMonth--;

        if (aMonth < 0) {
            aMonth = 11;
            aYear--;
        } 
    }

    monthList += '<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="?all">Show All</a></li>';

    $("#monthFilters").append(monthList);

});
```

See the error in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/imnotmarvin/pen/104c35aa794e9f57e8917c9a7cd7843d). No errors are showing in the console. Am I just too tired and missing something simple/stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not defining monthList as a string so you try to add a string to undefined. Just do this before your loop

```
  var monthList = "";
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I can't even accept your answer for another 7 min. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the `monthList` variable. In your code it has the value `undefined` so when you build the first `<li>` element the `undefined` word is attached.

Initialize it with an empty string, like

```
var monthList = "";
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! With two similar answers I'm only voting the other one because it came in a few seconds sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
var monthList;
```

to

```
var monthList="";
```